# Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and Gazebo.

I'm running through the "Gazebo ROS API for C-Turtle" tutorial and receive the following error:

```
Warning [parser.cc:332] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:271] parse as sdf version 1.0 failed, trying to parse as old deprecated format
Warning [parser.cc:277] parse as old deprecated world file failed, trying old model format.
Exception [ODELink.cc:317] Setting custom link desk1mass to zero!

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)
[empty_world_server-2] process has died [pid 2568, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/joe/.ros/log/4410c96e-bc79-11e1-b83e-00269ed0509d/empty_world_server-2.log].
log file: /home/me/.ros/log/4410c96e-bc79-11e1-b83e-00269ed0509d/empty_world_server-2*.log
```

In the terminal where I issued the spawn command, I receive a "successfully spawned model" message. However, I receive the above error and do not see a model in the world map. (does that last bit have to do with the desk1mass being set to 0?)

Do I have the incorrect version of Gazebo (Diamond back release as it's "recommended")  installed with ROS? I am running the most up to date version of ROS (12.04 on Ubuntu).

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37072/gazebo-sdf-has-no-gazebo-element/) by [sl0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/2556/sl0w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, your versions don't match. The tutorial is actually for C-Turtle and F(-uerte) is current and the oldest available for Precise.

I'd recommend using a newer tutorial/the other tutorials as you probably don't want to use C-Turtles gazebo, although some of the things are still valid in general. As the error looks maybe just choosing another newer model or updated spawn parameters might work. Unfortunately I can't check this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2